# Actor constructor taking array of ActorRefs

Tags: scala, parameters, constructor, akka, actor

I need to write a programme in Scala, which has 3 actors and one object - ball. One actor has to pass the ball to another. Actor's constructor has to include two arguments:

```
class Player(val num: Int, val players: Array[ActorRef]) extends Actor { … }
```

Here is my question: how can I invoke this constructor to make up three actors and in the same time pass the array of them into all of the actors?

Here is rest of my code:

```
case class Ball(count: Int)

class Player(val num: Int, val players: Array[ActorRef]) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Ball(count) =>
      println("I've got a ball!")
      var nextPlayer = self
      do {
        nextPlayer = players((Math.random() * 3).toInt)
      } while(nextPlayer == self)
      self.tell(Ball(count + 1), nextPlayer)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does your `Player` has `players` as a constructor argument? Is it explicitly required or is it just your idea to design it this way?

Comment: it is just prefered by teacher and I do not have an idea what else I could do.

Comment: You have created a circular dependency which is unfortunately not easy to solve. To be honest, I don't think this is the most effective way to use actors. You could have a parent actor generating players where these have to communicate with each other through the parent. This way, the parent can supervise the children and restart them/handle exceptions if something happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that your whole logic is a bit broken. The simple solution would be to have a parent actor called e.g. `Game`. Logically, multiple `Player's` can participate in a single game. So, it should look something like this:

```
import akka.actor.{ Actor, ActorLogging, ActorRef, Props }

object Game {
  final case class StartGame(playerCount: Int)
  def apply() = Props(new Game)
}

final class Game extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import Game._
  var players = Set.empty[ActorRef]

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case StartGame(playerCount) =>
      for (i <- 1 to playerCount) {
        players = players + context.actorOf(Player.apply(playerCount), i.toString)
      }

    case (ball: Player.Ball, playerId: Int) =>
      context.child(playerId.toString) match {
        case Some(actorRef) => actorRef ! ball
        case None           => log.warning("Player not found!")
      }
  }
}

object Player {
  case class Ball(count: Int = 0)
  def apply(playerCount: Int) = Props(new Player(playerCount))
}

final class Player(playerCount: Int) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import Player._

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Ball(count) =>
      log.info(s"Player with id: ${self.path.name} has the ball --- Ball count: $count")
      context.parent ! (Ball(count + 1), 1 + (Math.random() * playerCount).toInt)
  }
}
```

So, instead that each `Player` actor has the reference toward other actors, the `Game` parent actor will have a collection of `Player` actors. When each `Player` "kicks" the `Ball`, the message is sent to parent actor and then dispatched the next selected actor.

Answer (score 0):

The contract which actors will use to talk to each other,

```
case object StartTheGame
case object StopTheGame

case class PlayerJoin(player: ActorRef)
case class PlayerLeave(player: ActorRef)
case class GetNextPlayer(player: ActorRef)

case class Ball(count: Int)
case class BallThrow(ball: Ball)
```

Player Actor,

```
class Player extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive = {
    case Ball(count) => {
      log.info("player has caught the ball - {}", self)
      sender() ! BallThrow(Ball(count + 1))
      log.info("player has thrown the ball - {}", self)
    }
  }
}

object Player {
  def props: Props = Props(classOf[Player])
}
```

Playground,

```
class PlayGround extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  var players = Set.empty[ActorRef]

  var gameOnGoing = false

  def passBallToNextPlayer(player: ActorRef, ball: Ball): Unit = {
    if (gameOnGoing) {
      getRandomNextPlayer(sender()) ! ball
    }
    else {
      log.info("Game has stopped. Ball is falling to the ground.")
    }
  }

  def getRandomNextPlayer(player: ActorRef): ActorRef = {
    val otherPlayers = (players - player).toVector
    val otherPlayersCount = otherPlayers.size
    if (otherPlayersCount > 0) {
      otherPlayers((Math.random() * (otherPlayersCount - 1)).toInt)
    }
    else {
      player
    }
  }

  override def receive = {
    case StartTheGame => startTheGame()
    case StopTheGame => stopTheGame()
    case PlayerJoin(player) => {
      log.info("A new player has joined the game - {}", player)
      players = players + player
    }
    case PlayerLeave(player) => {
      log.info("A player has left the game - {}", player)
      players = players - player
    }
    case BallThrow(ball) => passBallToNextPlayer(sender(), ball)
  }

  def startTheGame(): Unit = {
    gameOnGoing = true
    players.head ! Ball(0)
  }

  def stopTheGame(): Unit = {
    gameOnGoing = false
  }

}

object PlayGround {
  def props: Props = Props(classOf[PlayGround])
}
```

The game,

```
object Akka1 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val actorSystem = ActorSystem("game_system")

    val playGround = actorSystem.actorOf(PlayGround.props)

    playGround ! PlayerJoin(actorSystem.actorOf(Player.props))
    playGround ! PlayerJoin(actorSystem.actorOf(Player.props))
    playGround ! PlayerJoin(actorSystem.actorOf(Player.props))

    playGround ! StartTheGame
  }

}
```